# What does List<List<Integer>> arr mean

Tags: java

```
public static int diagonalDifference(List<List<Integer>> arr) {
// Write your code here

}
```

what does this function parameter actually mean 2D list or what

i'm just trying to make a something that calculate the sum of a diagonal of numbers

Comment: *actually mean 2D list* - yes

Comment: to be precise it's a jagged array, not a rectangular 2D array like a matrix

Comment: It's a list of lists.

Comment: In this specific case, it's how HackerRank chose to specify a square matrix of integers as the API for solving the [Diagonal Difference](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/diagonal-difference/problem) problem. The outer `List` are the rows, and each row is a `List<Integer>` of the columns in that row.